# Keep getting error `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable' when trying to run file using numpy library

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I intend to perform a Newton Raphson iteration on some data I read in from a file. I use the following function in my python program.

```
def newton_raphson(r1, r2): 
    guess1 = 2 * numpy.log(2) / (numpy.pi() * (r1 + r2))
```

I call this function as so:

```
    if answer == "f":  # if data is in file
fileName = input("What is the name of the file you want to open?")
dataArray = extract_data_from_file(fileName)
resistivityArray = []
for i in range(0, len(dataArray[0])):
    resistivity_point = newton_raphson(dataArray[0][i], dataArray[1][i])
    resistivityArray += [resistivity_point]
```

On running the program and entering my file, this returns `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable'. Everything I've read online suggests this is due to missing an operator somewhere in my code, but I can't see where I have. Why do I keep getting this error and how do I avoid it?

Comment: You appear to be calling `pi` which is a constant, not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.pi` is not a function, it is a constant:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.pi
3.141592653589793
```

Remove the `()` call from it:

```
def newton_raphson(r1, r2): 
    guess1 = 2 * numpy.log(2) / (numpy.pi * (r1 + r2))
```

as that is causing your error:

```
>>> numpy.pi()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```